# Give a delay on Entry textchanged event in python and tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a problem in my code ,

I was using python and tkinter to develop my programs,

but i have a problem that make me stuck for a while ,

i was build an Employee Attandance application,

An employee have an ID ,
so in my application Employee input his/her id on textboxt in my form

like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdxcH.png)

the problem is ,each employee has len(id) between 9 and 10

so i think i create an event triggered start after len(id) input is 9

```
ids = StringVar(value="")
ids.trace("w", lambda name, index, mode, ids=ids: textchanged(ids))
inputid = tkinter.Entry(window,font="Helvetica 20 bold",textvariable=ids)
inputid.pack()
inputid.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.187,width=300,height=30,anchor='sw',)
inputid.size()

def textchanged(ids):
id = ids.get()
if len(id) >= 9:
    time.sleep(3)
    print(id)
    compareimage(id)
```

the problem is ,the textbox stop to get input after 8 char id input in textbox
I can't input until 9 length id in my textbox

but in my console it can still print untul 9 lenght id

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFjjw.png)

how can i solve this,

can anyone please help me?

i add this code to my question

```
def compareimage(id):
    try:
        path = folder + id
        ClassNames = []
        mylist = os.listdir(path)
        for cls in mylist:
            curImg = cv2.imread(f'{path}/{cls}')
            image.append(curImg)
            ClassNames.append(os.path.splitext(cls)[0])
        encodeListKnown = finencode(image)
        print(encodeListKnown)
        print(ClassNames)
        print(mylist)
        time.sleep(3)
        while (True):
            ret, frames = cap.read()
            frames =cv2.flip(frames,1)
            gray = cv2.cvtColor(frames, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            imgS = cv2.resize(frames, (0, 0), None, 0.25, 0.25)
            imgS = cv2.resize(frames, (0, 0), None, 0.25, 0.25)
            imgS = cv2.cvtColor(imgS, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            facecurentframe = face_recognition.face_locations(imgS)
            encodecurframe = face_recognition.face_encodings(imgS, facecurentframe)
            encodelistface = []
            for faceloc in zip(encodecurframe, facecurentframe):
                encodeface = faceloc[0]
                encodelistface.append(encodeface)
            matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(encodeListKnown, encodelistface[0])
            facedistance = face_recognition.face_distance(encodeListKnown, encodelistface[0])
            print(encodelistface)
            print(facedistance)
            print(matches)
            a = str(matches)
            print(bool(matches))
            if (bool(matches) == True):
                print("True")
                now = datetime.now()
                stringnow = now.strftime('%y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
                f = open(foldertxt, "a")
                logabsen = id + " , "+ stringnow  + "\n"
                f.write(logabsen )
                playsound(folderaudio)
                encodelistface.clear()
                encodeListKnown.clear()
                image.clear()
                ClassNames.clear()
                inputid.delete(0,END)
                break
            else:
                print("False")
                encodelistface.clear()
                encodeListKnown.clear()
                image.clear()
                ClassNames.clear()
                inputid.delete(0,END)
                break
    except :
        print("There is An Exception" , sys.exc_info()[0])
```

Comment: `tkinter.Entry(..., width=9)`

Comment: @MichaelGuidry: no, that only changes the visual size, it doesn't affect how many characters can be entered or when the callback is called.

Comment: def textchanged(ids):
    id = ids.get()
    if len(id) >= 9:
        print(str(id))
 i have no problem about this,it can run succesfully ,

but when i run with this 
def textchanged(ids):
    id = ids.get()
    if len(id) >= 9:
        print(str(id))
       compare(id)

Comment: def compareimage(id):
    try:
        path = folder + id
        ClassNames = []
        mylist = os.listdir(path)
        for cls in mylist:
            curImg = cv2.imread(f'{path}/{cls}')
            image.append(curImg)
            ClassNames.append(os.path.splitext(cls)[0])
        encodeListKnown = finencode(image)
        print(encodeListKnown)

Comment: it cause a problem , i don't know how can i happen ,but i wish anyone can help me

Comment: @rickifernando ~ posting code in comments is a terrible way to get help. You already asked the question. If you have more info you should add it to the question.

Comment: I don't think using `trace()` to trigger the action is not a good way.  Why not just wait for `<Return>` key event to trigger the action or use a button instead of `trace()`?

Comment: that;s was the problem,i think it's solved if i can use button,but the problem is i cannot use button,because this situation is a pandemic , so we try to reduce contact with surrounding objects , so i think i cannot use a button, if i use a textbox ,employee can scan his / her id card on the barcode machine , without touch any object

Comment: Can you configure the barcode scanner to append a newline character at the end of the ID scanned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refactored your script and removed all the unnecessary fluff. I also removed your wait and the `compareimage` call that you did not provide. It works fine. My guess is that either the wait or the call to `compareimage` were stealing focus from and/or blocking your `Entry`. If you take my version of your script and add in the `wait` and call, one at a time, you should be able to figure out what is blocking your `Entry`.

Note: There is no reason to call `pack` before `place`, and I have no clue what `size()` is supposed to do. `ids` is already global so, all the hoops you jumped through to plug it into a `lambda` were unnecessary. If something is `>= 9` it is also simply `> 8`

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('800x600+300+300')

ids = tk.StringVar(value="")

inputid = tk.Entry(root, font="Helvetica 20 bold", textvariable=ids)
inputid.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.187, width=300, height=30, anchor='sw')

def textchanged(*args):
    id = ids.get()
    if len(id) > 8:
        print(id)
        
ids.trace("w", textchanged)
        
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: i have try this, 
and it was not succesfully

Comment: @rickifernando ~ it wasn't succesfully in what way? You can type more than 8 characters and it prints the id when you do. I'm positive it works to that degree so, whatever you have try, it wasn't this.

Comment: when call back compareimage(ids),
it was not fully failed , because it still show full id in console,but the problem is in the textbox widget , cannot show more than 8 len character

Answer (score 1):

You can use `after()` to schedule a timeout task whenever `inputid` is updated. You need to pick a timeout period that is long enough between each update of `inputid` by the barcode scanner.  If `inputid` is updated again before the scheduled timeout, you need to cancel the previous timeout task and rescheduled anther one.

If the timeout task is triggered, you can perform the face recognition in the timeout callback, but suggest to use thread to do it as it may be a time consuming task which will block `tkinter` main loop.

Below is an example:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import random
import threading
import time

def compareimage(id):
    face.config(text='Checking ...', image=tk.PhotoImage())
    face.update_idletasks()
    # simulate the face recognition task
    time.sleep(5)
    # show the result image
    face.image = tk.PhotoImage(file='result.png')
    face.config(text=id, image=face.image)
    ids.set('')

def text_completed(ids):
    print('timed out')
    id = ids.get()
    if len(id) > 8:
        print('id:', id)
        threading.Thread(target=compareimage, args=(id,), daemon=True).start()

def text_changed(ids):
    global timeout_id
    if timeout_id:
        # cancel previous scheduled task
        root.after_cancel(timeout_id)
    if len(ids.get()) > 0:
        # schedule a timeout task, adjust the delay to suit your real situation
        timeout_id = root.after(1000, text_completed, ids)

# simulate barcode reader input
def scan_id(n=10):
    if n > 0:
        inputid.insert('end', random.choice('1234567890'))
        inputid.after(50, scan_id, n-1)

timeout_id = None

root = tk.Tk()

tk.Label(root, text='Employee Attandance', font='Helvetica 32 bold').pack()

ids = tk.StringVar(value='')
ids.trace('w', lambda *args: text_changed(ids))

inputid = tk.Entry(root, font='Helvetica 20 bold', textvariable=ids, width=12)
inputid.pack()

face = tk.Label(root, text='', image=tk.PhotoImage(), compound='top', width=600, height=400)
face.pack()

tk.Button(root, text='Scan ID', command=lambda: scan_id(random.randrange(9,11))).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Note that the button `Scan ID` is to simulate the barcode reader.